# How to - Google Calendar event creator is not a Google user

Tags: api, calendar

We have web application including calendar functionality. Now I want to add possibility to link your local calendar with Google Calendar through API.

As not every user will link the calendar I expect following situation to occure (often):

- User has not linked her Google Calendar with our web application;
- User is creating event in our application;
- User adds another user to the event who has synced her application calendar to Google Calendar and has expetation that all her events are evenly distributed;

How to create event to that participant user Google calendar so that she is participant not organiser?
Why it is important - when invited user updates any information in Google in regular case she gets notice by Google that all her changes can be overwritten by organiser. Also some fields cannot be changed at all from mobile.

There are limits on how many events we can create through the API as organizers by ourselves so at this point we are not considering creating artificial google users to be creators for the events.

Comment: With one sentence:

I need to send to users google calendar event through API where the user is not the owner/creator of the event without involving the original author (is not a google user)

Comment: Who owns the calendars? Could you use a service account?

Comment: Service account is not very scalable. There are limits on how many events you can create per day or you vill be sliently muted.

Comment: One option I have found out so far is to send API owner e-mail regardless the API. In that way they can be participants and not owners.
Will check if that can be saved if "sender" won't have google account.